# a word meaning, "from hardest to easiest."

Tags: single-word-requests

Im looking for a word that means "in order from hardest to easiest."

I could say "in ascending order, from hardest to easiest," but am wondering if that phrase is encapsulated by one word.

Comment: I don't think there's a special word for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:
in order of decreasing difficulty

Answer (score 1):

Saying "in ascending order, from hardest to easiest" is redundant.  You can just say "from hardest to easiest".

I don't know of a single word, but something like "difficulty rating" or "difficulty ranking" might work.

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest an alternative: `progressively easier`

For example:

```
It is getting progressively easier to build what you design.
```